# Traversing columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with following columns

```
StationID, Station1, Station2, Station3, Station4
```

Then I want to check (for a given row) data in each column against something.

So how do I do it.
Basically what do I put in ... that it becomes a variable and auto-increments itself

```
IF Station[...] IS NULL THEN
```

Don't worry about incrementing beyond number of columns because Station4 has all values as NULL acting as termination condition

Comment: You might want to explain your use case instead of just what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Devon  I want to trigger the if condition the first time it encounters null in the columns of a specific row. Example, a row is [1, A, B, NULL, NULL] then I want to trigger the if condition after B although I also want to know at which column it triggered

Comment: basically something like Station$i and i incrementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly,you want to find the first column which has a null value for a given row.I think you can acheive that using the CASE operator

```
SELECT
   (CASE WHEN stationID IS NULL THEN 'stationID'
        WHEN station1 IS NULL THEN 'station1'
        WHEN station2 IS NULL THEN 'station2' 
        WHEN station3 IS NULL THEN 'station3'
        WHEN station4 IS NULL THEN 'station4'
        ELSE 'no_null' END) as first_null_column
from <table>
WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: I was thinking of something that could save us from writing all the column names individually provided that the columns are all same with an incrementing value